# How to set the HomeScreen image without using method HomeScreen.setBackgroundImage(url)?

Tags: blackberry

Can anyone help me out as I am looking for a method that helps me to set the wallpaper using the images from the Pictures folder on Blackberry Curve 8310.

I found one method HomeScreen.setBackground(url), but it doen't works on Blackberry Curve.

I am using Operating system 4.5 and this method is useable with operating systems 4.7 & above

So, i want to know is their any method for blackberry curve to set the wallpaper or is their any operating system that supports the above method?

Kindly reply

Thanks a lot

Best Regards,

Richa Bhatia

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like this is possible before the 4.7 SDK. See MSohm's response in this [post](http://208.74.204.192/t5/Java-Development/Workaround-to-set-current-image-as-Homescreen-Background-image/td-p/459271).

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for the sample.
But i read somewhere that getBitmapResource() looks for the resource in both the .cod file that called this method and any .cod files that it relies on. But my images are not stored in the .cod files. Instead they are stored in the SDCard and i need to pass the path of the images randomnly to set the blackberry wallpapers.

So, how i can made this thing possible.

Please reply

Thanks & Regards,
Richa Bhatia

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. It works fine. But this method is used to set the image in the Background of our own application and i want to set the image as wallpaper i.e. at Blackberry's HomeScreen. And i feel that this method won't work for me. 
I have the url's of all the images stored in the Blackberry's SDCard and i want to set those images as the wallpaper randomnly.
I have HomeScreen.setBackground(url) method for STorm but it won't work with Blackberry Curve. So, i just want a method that works with the Operating system 4.5.
Kindly help me

Thanks a lot.
Best Regards,
Richa Bhatia

Comment: Sorry, I completely misunderstood your question. I have updated my answer. As far as I can tell it is not possible before 4.7.

Comment: Hi cmour,
No need to say sorry. :)
And thanks a lot for your kind help as i learnt something new from your answers.
Thanks again.

Best Regards,
Richa Bhatia